# Error while building Android source code (version 4.1.1_r6): trouble processing "javax/net/ServerSocketFactory.class":

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

I am trying to build android source code version 4.1.1_r6. Everything was working fine but suddenly I am getting error "trouble processing "javax/net/ServerSocketFactory.class"

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks...

Comment: Any more errors except that "trouble processing..."?

Comment: Can you simply describe the steps you build the project? Have you done a lunch?

Answer (score 0):

Goto project-->properties->java build path->libraries-> remove all including android jars

Go to the project browser, right click on the project you are working on, then android tools---> fix project properties...

Next, clean and then build...

Comment: Its not about any particular project. I am trying to build android source code using terminal and make command.